# Send file over serial with Arduino control

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I am making a simple ROM programer and would like it to be stand alone (no PC side software).

I have the arduino setup to accept a raw flow of data (file drag/drop or copy/paste) but the transmit rate is faster than the ROM write speed and my buffer fills up.

I compensated by communicating at 9600baud but that's a terrible solution. Is there a standard flow control protocol for serial file transfers that clients like Putty understand? I don't want to write any PC side program which means I need to use something common.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities how to control flow:

- Software flow control - by sending special characters XON (ASCII 17)/XOFF (ASCII 19)
- Hardware flow control - by using RTS and CTS. This way is much better, however RTS is used for uploading code into the Arduino so if you don't want surprising restarts, you have to disable this auto reset feature (or enable it if you need reflash new firmware).